# Problem with Jinja code if condition in django web application

Tags: django, jinja2

I am trying to use an if condition in html using jinja code, The Boolean value called "is_verified" is false. But the code prints exactly opposite of what it is expected to do, What's going wrong here?

```
{% for info in infos %}
{% if info.is_verified == "false" %}
<h4>Verification status: PENDING</h4>
{% else %}
<h4>Verification status: APPROVED</h4>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing it with a string "false". Instead, use this;

```
{% for info in infos %}
{% if info.is_verified %} 
<h4>Verification status: APPROVED</h4>
{% else %}
<h4>Verification status: PENDING</h4>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Okay so for boolean values it by default considers this as true? Thanks it works